# Rails controller test, when url path doesn't match controller path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes

I have this in my routes.rb:

```
get "user/:id" => "game_week#show_all"
```

The controller is kept in app/controllers/game_week_controller.rb.

Now, I'm trying to call this method, in game_week_controller_test.rb:

```
test "call rejected if user if user doesn't exist" do
  post :show_all, user_id: 10
  assert_response :not_found
end
```

This is throwing the error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:user_id=>"10", :controller=>"game_week", :action=>"show_all"}
```

I don't know exactly how these are formed. It can't be looking for "game_week#show_all". So it must be looking for /game_week/show_all as a route. How can I make sure I post to user/:id from game_week_controller_test.rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined a `get` route but you have `post` called from your spec:

Use the following:

```
get :show_all, id: 10
```

Also, note that the parameter is `id` not `user_id`.

Comment: Yeah you're right, that's exactly it. I'd delete the question out of embarrassment, if I didn't want to select this as the answer for you :)